# change style if the checkbox comes checked when page loaded

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, checkbox, user-controls

I am using a usercontrol in which a gridview with html checkboxes are present.I am using this control in another page. Some of these checkboxes comes checked when the user control in the page is loaded.

So in order to change the style of checkboxes when the usercontrol loads, this is the jquery code I have added in a js file,

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chk">

jQuery('input:checkbox.chk').click(evaluate).each(evaluate);

function evaluate() {
    debugger;
    var item = jQuery(this);
    alert('hello');
    if (item.is(":checked")) {
        jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
    } else {}
}
```

But this is not firing at all. what's wrong in the code. Can any one please help me out in solving this.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any error in console ?

Comment: @dreamweiver!  No error!

Comment: actually i dont find any problem with your code, its working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/Da4Lz/8/

Comment: Yes I too tested in jsfiddle. But the problem comes when the page is loaded in asp.net.

Comment: if your linking this js file within your asp.net  page, then may be you need to call this function within `$(document).ready(....)` of your asp.net page. so that when the asp.net page`s dom tree is completely loaded the js function will be loaded as well in to your asp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three things to do

- Add code in doucument.ready
- You do not need each here.
- use change instead of click

Binding event,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('input:checkbox.chk').change(evaluate);
});
```

Defining function

```
 function evaluate() {
    debugger;
    var item = jQuery(this);
    alert('hello');
    if (item.is(":checked")) {
        jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
    } else {
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

May be you miss `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Put your code here
})
```

Comment: I am linking the javascript file in the page. So it should automatically fire the code. I dont know where it fails!!

Comment: If you want script automatically fire in code, you must define `onclick` in HTML like as
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" onclick="yourFunction();">

At here, you use Jquery, so events which you want to bind into selectors , you must define after 
`$(document).ready(function(){

})`

Answer (score 1):

Move this code to pageinit function of first page or document.ready event.

```
if (item.is(":checked")) {
    jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass("active");

} 
else {

}
```